# Printing a diamond shape in ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

```py
import math

num_rows = int(input())
if num_rows % 2 != 0:
    upper_mid = math.ceil(num_rows/2)
    lower_mid = num_rows//2
    
    #prints upper normal triangle
    for row in range(0, upper_mid):                 
        for col in range(upper_mid-1, row, -1):     
            print(end=" ")                         
        for col in range(row+1):                  
            print('*', end="")
        for col in range(row):                   
            print('*', end="")
        print()
    
    # prints lower inverted triangle 
    for row in range(0, lower_mid):                
        for col in range(row+1):                    
            print(end=" ")
        for col in range(lower_mid - row):         
            print('*', end="")
        for col in range(lower_mid - row-1):    
            print('*', end="")
        print()
else:
    print("Only odd numbers!")
```

Input:

```
9
```

Ouput:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

This code works 100%, and prints a diamond shape star pattern. I'm a beginner in Python, and wrote this by myself, so I might have written something unnecessary and the code could be simplified, or something else. Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `print` is very slow, you should focus on building strings then have one print. Fortunately Python has some really nice string manipulation options.

> ```py
> for col in range(upper_mid-1, row, -1):
>     print(end=" ")
> ```

- You should rename `col` to `_`, which is standard nomenclature to say the variable is thrown away.
- Since the print isn't based on `col` walking up (`step=1`) would be easier to understand.

  ```py
  for _ in range(row, upper_mid - 1):
  ```
- We can instead use `*` with a string and an integer to duplicate the string that amount of times.

  ```py
  output = " " * (upper_mid - 1 - row)
  ```

Lets convert your code to remove the `range`s, and a number of prints.
I'm also remove the whitespace at the end of lines, something which you should never have.

```py
num_rows = int(input())
if num_rows % 2 != 0:
    upper_mid = math.ceil(num_rows/2)
    lower_mid = num_rows//2

    #prints upper normal triangle
    for row in range(0, upper_mid):
        print(
            " " * (upper_mid - 1 - row)
            + "*" * (row + 1)
            + "*" * row
        )

    # prints lower inverted triangle 
    for row in range(0, lower_mid):
        print(
            " " * (row + 1)
            + "*" * (lower_mid - row)
            + "*" * (lower_mid - 1 - row)
        )
else:
    print("Only odd numbers!")
```

- We can see the two loops for the upper and lower triangle are very similar.
  If we change the lower triangle to walk from `lower_mid - 1` down, then the inner parts would be the same.
- We can also see we can merge the two lines creating the stars with `row * 2 + 1`

```py
num_rows = int(input())
if num_rows % 2 != 0:
    upper_mid = math.ceil(num_rows/2)
    lower_mid = num_rows//2
    for row in range(0, upper_mid):
        print(
            " " * (upper_mid - 1 - row)
            + "*" * (2 * row + 1)
        )
    for row in reversed(range(0, lower_mid)):
        print(
            " " * (upper_mid - 1 - row)
            + "*" * (2 * row + 1)
        )
else:
    print("Only odd numbers!")
```

I wouldn't expect a beginner to know these.
But there are some more advanced improvements we can make:

- Making a function, to increase reusability of the code.
- Using `itertools.chain` to let us not write the same body for the for loops twice.
- Changing `num_rows % 2 != 0` to a guard clause to reduce the arrow anti-pattern.
- We know `lower_mid = upper_mid - 1`, so we can replace `upper_mid - 1` with `lower_mid` and remove the need for using `math.ceil`.
- Use `"\n".join` and a generator expression to return just a string to be printed.
- Use typehints to document the types the function takes and returns.

```py
import itertools


def diamond(size: int) -> str:
    if size % 2 == 0:
        raise ValueError("only odd numbers are allowed")
    mid = size // 2
    return "\n".join(
        " " * (mid - half_width) + "*" * (2 * half_width + 1)
        for half_width in itertools.chain(
            range(0, mid + 1),
            reversed(range(0, mid)),
        )
    )


print(diamond(int(input("Size of diamond: "))))
```

Comment: Btw "Calling print is very slow, you should focus on building strings then have one print..." can you elaborate further? Is this what you meant: """   print(
            " " * (upper_mid - 1 - row)
            + "*" * (2 * row + 1)   """ instead of  """ print(end='') """ and a bunch of other print functions?

Comment: @Anony I don't know the actual average time of a print, but lets play a number game. Say a single call to `print` takes \$10^{-2}\$ seconds. If you have 10 calls then your code would take \$10^{-1}\$ seconds to complete. On the other hand joining strings using `+` takes \$10^{-3}\$ seconds, so if we have 10 of them the code would take \$10^{-2}\$ seconds, and an additional \$10^{-2}\$ for the one call to `print`. Suddenly the code runs in 1/5 of the time. So yes, deferring to `print` for string manipulation is normally a bad habit.

Comment: For more context on you can read one of rolfl's [answers on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/246535).

Comment: Strangely this reminds me of an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913437/create-a-bowtie-pattern-with-python-3-0/59913538#59913538) I did on SO regarding a bowtie pattern - diamonds and bowties must be a common thing these days...